# Brainjs dynamique array

Tags: node.js, arrays, brain.js

Quick question about BrainJs -> In server side.
I'm doing a neuronal that works with string so I encode everything and fill the shorter array with 0 values. But I'm wondering something.What if the user writes a string longer than all the strings I used in my dataset ?
So I tried and it didn't crash but I'm wondering if Brainjs is using all the value of the new longer string?

Thanks in advance for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some tests this is my conclusion.

The longest array in my dataset is a size of 10, after the training the AI thinks this array is a class 1 at 0.987... chances.

I try to give an array of size 50 to the AI, but the 10 first digits are the same as the first array. The AI answer class 1 at 0.987... chances (In fact this is exactly the same result than before). That seems logic, I think other digit of the array are ignored because of the lack of the neurons.